# How to apply CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter on CIImage?

Tags: swift, ciimage

I am following [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/508/) WWDC lecture.

In the lecture he mentions a filter named "CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter" that makes the edges more preserved and upsampled.
I am trying to apply this on my CIImage and I get an uninitialized result for the Image and crashes.

This is the code I am using and an example of how I try to apply the filter (which is obviously wrong). I just cannot find any related instructions for applying this filter, I just know I want its results on my image.
I comment next to where I try to apply the filter, and what happens when I do it.

```
func createMask(for depthImage: CIImage, withFocus focus: CGFloat, andScale scale: CGFloat, andSlope slope: CGFloat = 4.0, andWidth width: CGFloat = 0.1) -> CIImage {

    let s1 = slope
    let s2 = -slope
    let filterWidth =  2 / slope + width
    let b1 = -s1 * (focus - filterWidth / 2)
    let b2 = -s2 * (focus + filterWidth / 2)

    let mask0 = depthImage
        .applyingFilter("CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
            "inputRVector": CIVector(x: s1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputGVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: s1, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputBVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: s1, w: 0),
            "inputBiasVector": CIVector(x: b1, y: b1, z: b1, w: 0)])
        .applyingFilter("CIColorClamp").applyingFilter("CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter") //returns uninitialized image

    let mask1 = depthImage
        .applyingFilter("CIColorMatrix", withInputParameters: [
            "inputRVector": CIVector(x: s2, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputGVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: s2, z: 0, w: 0),
            "inputBVector": CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: s2, w: 0),
            "inputBiasVector": CIVector(x: b2, y: b2, z: b2, w: 0)])
        .applyingFilter("CIColorClamp")

    var combinedMask = mask0.applyingFilter("CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter", withInputParameters: ["inputBackgroundImage" : mask1]) //complete crash
    if PortraitModel.sharedInstance.filterArea == .front {
        combinedMask = combinedMask.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert")
    }
    let mask = combinedMask.applyingFilter("CIBicubicScaleTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputScaleKey: scale])

    return mask
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime headers and some usage code I've found seems to suggest that CIEdgePreserveUpsampleFilter does not take a `inputBackgroundImage` parameter, but rather `inputSmallImage`.

See https://gist.github.com/HarshilShah/ca0e18db01ce250fd308ab5acc99a9d0